# SQL query design for getting a table with column depending on a column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7, pivot

I would like to do a SQL query in SQL Server to get a table:

Table1:

```
  id  t value
  1   R  2412
  1   Q 98797
  2   R 132
  2   Q 7589
```

I need to get table:

```
 id   R_value   Q_value
 1      2412     98797
 2      132      7589
```

I used case and when, but I got

```
id   R_value   Q_value
 1      2412     null
 1      null     98797
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70e30/1/0)

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t = 'R' THEN value END) AS R_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t = 'Q' THEN value END) AS Q_value
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` or `min` with the `group by` to get rid of `null` values and aggregate rows with the same `id`:

```
select id
     , min(case when t = 'R' then value end) as R_value
     , min(case when t = 'Q' then value end) as Q_value
from tbl
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  R AS R_value,
  Q AS Q_value
FROM table1 AS t1
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR t IN(R, Q)
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd4ae/2)

This will give you:

```
| id | R_value | Q_value |
|----|---------|---------|
|  1 |    2412 |   98797 |
|  2 |     132 |    7589 |
```

Comment: DO we need 'R' as R_value ? Otherwise, it does not work.  thanks

Comment: NO, you can make it srlect * instead